# Is there a SQL function for removing strings that have text and integers, and how do I use it?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to remove all entries within the "Car Models" column that have a string of integers and text. For example, I would like to remove the entries  "100", "CT100", "Charger 300" from my results, leaving entries with only letters.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Car_Models AS 'Car Models'
FROM Car_Customers
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Car_Models) = 0
ORDER BY Car_Models ASC
```

My result returned entries with just text or texts/integers. I do not want the text/integers, I only need a list of entries with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT` [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Car_Models as 'Car Models'
FROM Car_Customers
WHERE Car_Models NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
ORDER BY Car_Models ASC
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `NOT LIKE`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Car_Models as 'Car Models'
FROM Car_Customers
WHERE Car_Models NOT LIKE '%[0123456789]%'
ORDER BY Car_Models ASC
```